# What's wrong with this function? not assignable?

Tags: c, microcontroller

```
float tempC(unsigned int adc_value) {
    multiplier = adc_value / 1023.0f;
    tempC = -40 * multiplier * 90;
    return tempC;
}
```

I am trying to use the ADC on a micro-controller to convert a potentiometer into temperature between -40 and 50 degrees C, the `adc_value` is the range given by the ADC however I get the error:

> Main.c:110:11: error: non-object type 'float (unsigned int)' is not
> assignable

I can provide more code if needed but I don't know where I'm going wrong as I am quite new to C and programming.

Comment: `tempC` is the name of your function. You can't assign to a function. Do you come from Pascal?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on floating point calculations if possible – and much less on microcontroller. You have unsigned input, so you won't ever get positive values if you multiply by -40.

Comment: `multiplier` is not defined here.  global?  type?

Comment: Apart from silly typos, you need to specify at what voltage level your ADC gives -50 degrees and 90 degrees. The relevant reference points will be the ADC values corresponding to these. Assuming that the function can be assumed to be linear.

Comment: Would we have to assume 0 corresponding to -40 °C, UINT_MAX to +50 °C?

Comment: @Aconcagua yes 0 is -40°C and max is 1023 corresponding to 50°C

Comment: Shouldn’t that be `-40 + multiplier * 90`?  Also, you should be dividing by `1024`, not `1023` (`0..1023` is 1024 distinct values).

Comment: I'd recommend fixed-comma arithmetics then, e. g. calculations in milligrade, which would look like this: `(adc_value * 90000 + 512)/1024 - 40000` – `+512` is for correct rounding. Result should be assigned to signed integer value.

Comment: @Aconcagua thankyou for the suggestion i will update now

Comment: Assuming -40C corresponds to 0 AD, and +50C to 1023 AD, the formula is `ad*90/1023-40` (that's 1023, not 1024).  It also works for integer (preferred -- avoid floats unless there is no simpler way). Scale for the number of decimals you'd like, e.g. `ad*900/1023-40` for a single decimal, `ad*9000/1023-40` for two, and so on.  If using integers beware of overflows, and reduce constant ratios so that instead of 9000/1023 use 3000/341 (although the compiler may be smart enough to do this automatically).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`tempC` is not a variable but the function, so you cannot assign there.

You should declare another variable instead of that like this:

```
float tempC(unsigned int adc_value) {
    float tempC_ret;
    multiplier = adc_value / 1023.0f;
    tempC_ret = -40 * multiplier * 90;
    return tempC_ret;
}
```

Or you can return the calculated value directly like this:

```
float tempC(unsigned int adc_value) {
    multiplier = adc_value / 1023.0f;
    return -40 * multiplier * 90;
}
```

Comment: `multiplier` is not defined

Comment: @ryyker Though it is not disclosed, it may be defined as a global variable (looks not so good design if then, though)

Comment: The core of the main question here is addressed by your answer, but I think the conversion algorithm is bogus.

Comment: Agreed, @ryyker.  At a guess, what they really want is `-40 + multiplier * 90`, though that's still making some assumptions about the measurand values at the extremes of the ADC's range.

Answer (score 2):

`tempC`is your function name, thus, the line:

```
tempC = -40 * multiplier *90;
```

Is trying to assign a value to the function, which is not possible.

To return the value, just:

```
return -40 * multiplier *90;
```

.

```
float tempC(unsigned int adc_value)
{
    float multiplier = adc_value / 1023.0f;
    return -40 * multiplier * 90;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the `C` syntax issue has been resolved, I believe there still remains
the problem of mapping one range of numbers to another. The expression:

```
tempC = -40 * multiplier * 90;
```

always yields a negative number, therefore not likely doing what you need.

*Mapping...*
You are using `unsigned int`.  Your code indicates the 2 byte varient , making the `adc_value` range from your uP `0 - 65535`.
The output range is given as -40 to 50
The problem is to map from one to the other.

Given these ranges,
ADC input start `0` maps to output start of `-40.0`
ADC input end `65535` maps to output end of `50.0`
The incremental change in output for each digit of change in input is then:

```
float multiplier = 1.0*(50.0f -(-40.0f))/65535;
```

The output value will then be:

```
-40.0f + multiplier*adc_value;
```

This translates to

```
float tempC(unsigned int adc_value)
{
    double multiplier = 1.0*(50.0f -(-40.0f))/(65535);

    return -40.0f + multiplier * adc_value; 
}
```